# Derivate in $L^p$ for convolution

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, convolution

Let $f \in L^p(R)$, if exists $h \in L^p(R)$ such that 
$$\displaystyle{lim_{y\to 0} \int_R \left|\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y} -h(x) \right|^p dx = 0} $$
The function $h$ is called the derivate $L^p$ of $f$. Prove that, if $g \in L^q(R)$, and the derivate $L^p$ of $f$ is $h$, then the point derivate of
$f*g$ is $h*g$

And show if $f \in L^p(R)$ and the derivate $L^p$ of $f$ exists, then $f$ is absolutely continuous in any bounded interval its point derivate in $L^p$.

Update. So far I have already managed to rpove thw first part:

$$
\left| \frac{f*g(x+y)-f*g(x)}{y} -h*g(x) \right| \to 0
$$
For this I used Hölder's inequality.
For the next part I have as a hint to use aproximation of identity, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Show ur thoughts bud

Comment: At first replace $\int_{\mathbb{R}}$ by $\int_a^b$ and set $p=1$, you get that $f = \int h dx$ where $h \in L^1([a,b])$

Comment: @mathworker21 I already updated what I have done so far.